# What are the scenarios in which I should use timestamps?

Tags: database, timestamp

What are the scenarios in which I should use timestamps? I know what a timestamp is, but I'd like to hear how it's helped folks in real-life projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I used an ORM (Linq2Sql or Enitity in my case), I read an interesting article by [Imar Spaanjaars](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1) about n-tiered in asp.net using ado.net.  In this example to handle concurrency, the timestamp column was checked when a record was returned, in say a gridview, and then checked on the database before an edit was made.  By comparing the timestamp in memory and in the database, you are able to see if a change was made between retrieving the record and then asking then reporting back to the user.

So in summary, I have used the timestamp column to handle concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Paul McCowat we also used to use timestamp for concurrency handling long ago.  With our switch to NHibernate (ORM) the trend is to use a simpler version number rather than timestamp.  The Rails framework uses version numbers instead of timestamps for concurrency as well.  We've pulled the timestamps from our database structure as we've migrated to newer ORM's.